# Are there any open source biomedical signal processing projects?

Tags: soft-question

I'm in a biomedical engineering master's program and am mostly interested in signal processing. Unfortunately, I feel that I'd like to get deeper into the subject, and my university can't accommodate that request -- there's a limited number of courses, and the professor I've asked doesn't know of any local project that I could join.

Are there any open source projects related to biomedical/bioelectric signal processing?

If not, could you recommend any other type of beneficial extracurricular activities? I could probably spend 1-2h a day on this project.

Comment: Does [brain imaging](http://nipy.org/) count?

Answer (score 2):

For image processing in biology, there is the [FIJI](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Fiji) project, a very worthwhile endeavor. They have a list of [project ideas](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Project_ideas) as well, maybe there's something that's perfect for you?

Answer (score 1):

[MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/) is a great resource containing free course materials for actual MIT courses. In the department of [Electrical Engineering and Computer Science](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/), there may be some courses of interest that you could go through. A quick look shows [Biomedical Signal and Image Processing](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-582j-biomedical-signal-and-image-processing-spring-2007/) and [Biomedical Computing](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-950j-biomedical-computing-fall-2010/), which might be up your alley.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in Yale's open course material on the subject: [Frontiers in Biomedical Engineering](http://oyc.yale.edu/biomedical-engineering/frontiers-in-biomedical-engineering/). It isn't focused on biomedical signal processing per se but discusses at some length the possibilities of engineering solutions in the biomedical industry.